# I need to select Year, AVG(score) where COUNT(id) is more than 1 grouped by year

Tags: sql, count

I have a table related to movies with the following columns.

```
id, year, score
```

First I needed to show the average score per year which I have already done.

```
SELECT
     year, AVG(score) 
FROM movies 
GROUP BY year DESC;
```

But now I need to do the same, but only where id per year (count) is higher than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
Select Year, AVG(score)
FROM movies
GROUP BY year
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY year desc;
```

The use of `desc` on `group by` is very MySQL specific.  I think it is better to have an explicit `order by`.